# Error getting document ReferenceError: from_data is not defined

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hi I'm stuck at the part where I get error when getting documents. I want to get the fields for users name.

This is the result i get from the console log: From user id: PGIfPp8wmnR1PB1XeiBfUgSnGO62From user: [object Promise] To user id [object Promise].

What am i doing wrong ?

**index.js**

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document('users/{userID}/notifications/{notificationID}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

        const user_id = context.params.userID;
        const notification_id = context.params.notificationID;

        console.log('We have notification from: ' + user_id + ' The notification id is: ' + notification_id);

        return db.collection('users').doc(user_id)
            .collection('notifications').doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {
                if (!queryResult.exists) {
                    console.log('No documents');
                }else{
                    console.log("Document data: " ,queryResult.data());
                    const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;
                    const from_data = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(from_user_id).get();
                    const to_data = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_id).get();

                    console.log("From user id: " + from_user_id + "From user: " + from_data + " To user id " + to_data);

                }
                return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {

                    const from_name = result[0].data().name;
                    const to_name = result[1].data().name;

                    return console.log("FROM: " + from_name + " TO: " + to_name);
                });
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.error('Error getting document', err);
            })
    });
```

**Error i get**

```
Error getting document ReferenceError: from_data is not defined
    at db.collection.doc.collection.doc.get.then.queryResult (/user_code/index.js:31:37)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

In these two lines:

```
const from_data = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(from_user_id).get();
const to_data = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(user_id).get();
```

You're assinging values to promises that will resolve with document data.  You haven't got actual document data yet.  You need to use the promises returned by `get()` to find the actual data, just like you're doing earlier in your function.

Comment: Sorry sir It's a good explanation but I still dont get it. I'm not that good with node.js or javascript. I'm implementing notifications function on my android app.